# Set multiple fields in prepared queries in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, prepared-statement

I am using 'mysql' library in Node

This is what i use instead of prepared statement, and works just fine :

```
 connection.query("update table set col1=? where col2=1",[val1],function(err,rows){
        //connection.release();
        if(!err) {
          //further code
          }
        });
```

However, this doesn't work for 2 unkowns :

```
    connection.query("update table set col1=? where col2=?",[val1],[val2],function(err,rows){
        //connection.release();
        if(!err) {
          //further code
          }
        });
```

The error message says "undefined is not a function". What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the values in a single array, like this:

```
connection.query("update table set col1=? where col2=?",[val1,val2],function(err,rows){
    //connection.release();
    if(!err) {
      //further code
      }
    });
```

All the necessary functionality can be easily found here: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#preparing-queries

Comment: Off-topic:Do you know about any similar complete module for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer. You can use something like [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), I suppose.

Comment: Couple of my update values have comma (,) in them which is messing up the query. What do I do to get rid of that?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the functionality I have provided? The library should escape values as [written here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values).